# sql selecting data from multiple temporary tables based on dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

The current query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
 (SELECT B.FILEKEY, B.STATUS AS STATUS, B.EFFDATE FROM TABLEB B
  UNION
  SELECT A.FILEKEY, A.STATUS2 AS STATUS, A.EFFDATE2 AS EFFDATE FROM TABLEA A) C
WHERE C.EFFDATE <= '5/1/2011')
ORDER BY C.EFFDATE DESC
```

yields the correct result of:

```
 Status Filekey  Effdate
    0      1       2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

based on unioned table C:

```
Filekey    Status    Effdate
  1           0         2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
  1           1         2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
  1           0         2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
  1           1         2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
  1           0         2009-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I now need to add in a new factor: location as of a specific date.

The unioned table F is generated as follows:

```
(SELECT E.FILEKEY, E.location, E.EFFDATE FROM TABLEE E
  UNION
  SELECT D.FILEKEY, D.location, D.LOCEFFDATE2 AS EFFDATE FROM TABLED D) F
```

What I'd really like to get is the following results:
Filekey, Status, Location all based on a specific date

what was the filekey's status and location as of a specific date?

Thanks for your help.  The expected output would look like:

```
Filekey      Status     Location
  1            0           2
```

Comment: So are you expecting Filekey, Status, Location as output based on ```EffDate``` obtained from first query?

Comment: no the effdate applies to each unioned table individually.  What is the filekey's status on the date?  What is the filekey's location on that same date?  Same date maximum for both status and location.

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: I added it to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
select c.FILEKEY, c.STATUS, d.location from
(select top 1 * from 
  (SELECT B.FILEKEY, B.STATUS, B.EFFDATE FROM tableB B 
   UNION
  SELECT A.FILEKEY, A.STATUS2, A.EFFDATE2 FROM tableA A) C
        where C.EFFDATE <= '5/1/2011'
        order by C.EFFDATE desc) D
inner join
(select top 1 * from 
  (SELECT F.FILEKEY, F.location, F.EFFDATE FROM tableF F
  UNION
  SELECT E.FILEKEY, E.location, E.loceffdate2 AS EFFDATE FROM tableE E) G
       where G.EFFDATE <= '5/1/2011'
       order by G.EFFDATE desc)  H   
on d.filekey=h.filekey
```